# Can I "undo" the reflexive pronoun, when using a pronominal verb?

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux

Pronouns can replace nouns. Can I take sentence with a verb used pronominally, and write a version of that sentence that restores the noun that the pronoun replaced?

example:

- Sarah **s'** est  demandé pourquoi elle ne peut pas pleurer.
- Sarah a demandé **à elle-même** pourquoi elle ne peut pas pleurer.

I am most curious about if I can do this with verbs that don't exist outside of their pronominal form:

- Je **m**'en vais.
- J'en vais **à moi**.
- Alice **s**'est ravisée.
- Alice a ravisé **à elle**.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot really do that, as it sounds really heavy and weird. That being said, every French people would understand the meaning of your sentence, though.

Comment: You just can't do it. It's not only "heavy and weird", it's grammatically incorrect (so obviously it sounds weird). I also doubt anybody will fully understand what you're saying when you say "J'en vais à moi" ou "Alice a ravisé à elle".